# How can I make an external toolbox available to a MATLAB Parallel Computing Toolbox job?

Tags: parallel-processing, external, matlab

As a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410339/parallelize-input-and-display-in-matlab) question and the subsequent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410339/parallelize-input-and-display-in-matlab/4411297#4411297), does anyone know how to have a job created using the Parallel Computing Toolbox (using `createJob` and `createTask`) access external toolboxes? Is there a configuration parameter I can specify when creating the function to specify toolboxes that should be loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this section of the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/bqur7ev-20.html#bqur7ev-27), one way you can do this is to specify either the [`'PathDependencies'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/pathdependencies.html) or the [`'FileDependencies'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/filedependencies.html) of the job object so that it points to the functions you need the job's workers to be able to use.

You should be able to point the way to the [`KbCheck` function](http://docs.psychtoolbox.org/KbCheck) in [PsychToolbox](http://psychtoolbox.org/wikka.php?wakka=HomePage), along with any other functions or directories needed for `KbCheck` to work properly. It would look something like this:

```
obj = createJob('PathDependencies',{'path_to_KbCheck',...
                                    'path_to_other_PTB_functions'});
```

Comment: Note that that form of createJob uses the default parallel configuration - if you have a scheduler object, you can also use sched.createJob( ... )

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing these out. I really wonder why they hid all that information in the "Using a third-party scheduler" part of the manual. In any event, I really apprecite the help!

Answer (score 2):

A few comments, based on my work troubleshooting this:

- It appears that there are inconsistencies with how well nested functions and anonymous functions work with the Parallel Computation toolkit. I was unable to get them to work, while [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410339/parallelize-input-and-display-in-matlab/4411297#4411297) have been able to. (Also see [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/252859).) As such, I would recommend having each function stored in it's own file, and including those files using the [`PathDependencies`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/pathdependencies.html) or [`FileDependencies`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/filedependencies.html)  properties, as described by gnovice above.
- It is very hard to troubleshoot the Parallel Computation toolkit, as everything happens outside your view. Use breakpoints liberally in your code, and the `inspect` command is your friend. Also note that if there is an error, task objects will contain an error parameter, which in turn will contain `ErrorMessage` string, and possibly the `Error.causes` MException object. Both of these were immensely useful in debugging.
- When including Psychtoolbox, you need to do it as follows. First, create a [`jobStartup.m`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/jobstartup.html) file with the following lines:

  ```
  PTB_path = '/Users/eliezerk/Documents/MATLAB/Psychtoolbox3/';
  addpath( PTB_path );
  cd( PTB_path );
  SetupPsychtoolbox;
  ```

  However, since the Parallel Computation toolkit can't handle any graphics functionality, running `SetupPsychtoolbox` as-is will actually cause your thread to crash. To avoid this, you need to edit the `PsychtoolboxPostInstallRoutine` function, which is called at the very end of `SetupPsychtoolbox`. Specifically, you want to comment out the line `AssertOpenGL` (line 496, as of the time of this answer; this may change in future releases).

Comment: I wonder if the inconsistencies in being able to use nested/anonymous functions is related at all to the versions of MATLAB or the Parallel Computing Toolbox being used. I had no problems when using R2009a for each (MATLAB version 7.8.0.347 and PCT version 4.1).

Comment: @gnovice - I'm running MATLAB 7.8.0.347 (R2009a) and PCT 4.1, so I guess not. I'm very curious as to the cause, but I don't think I have enough info to file a useful bug report about it.