# How to break a MATLAB system call after a specified number of seconds

Tags: matlab, shell, ssh, cmd

I am using Windows MATLAB to run SSH commands, but every once in a while the SSH command hangs indefinitely, and then so does my MATLAB script (sometimes when running overnight).  How can I have a command time-out after a certain amount of waiting time?  For example, suppose I don't want to wait more than 3 seconds for a SSH command to finish execution before breaking it and moving on:

```
% placeholder for a command that sometimes hangs
[status,result] = system('ssh some-user@0.1.2.3 sleep 10')
% placeholder for something I still want to run if the above command hangs
[status,result] = system('ssh some-user@0.1.2.3 ls')
```

I'd like to make a function `sys_with_timeout` that can be used like this:

```
timeoutDuration = 3;
[status,result] = sys_with_timeout('ssh some-user@0.1.2.3 sleep 10', timeoutDuration)
[status,result] = sys_with_timeout('ssh some-user@0.1.2.3 ls', timeoutDuration)
```

I've tried the [timeout function from FEX](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/61263-timeout) but it doesn't seem to work for a system/SSH command.

Comment: I've seen similar questions in the past, but I think none has a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @Cris Luengo's answer, here is the `sys_with_timeout()` function.  I didn't use the `process.waitFor()` function because I'd rather wait in a while loop and display output as it comes in.  The while loop breaks once the command finishes or it times out, whichever comes first.

```
function [status,cmdout] = sys_with_timeout(command,timeoutSeconds,streamOutput,errorOnTimeout)
    arguments
        command char
        timeoutSeconds {mustBeNonnegative} = Inf
        streamOutput logical = true    % display output as it comes in
        errorOnTimeout logical = false % if false, display warning only
    end
    % launch command as java process (does not wait for output)
    process = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    % start the timeout timer!
    timeoutTimer = tic();
    % Output reader (from https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/257278)
    outputReader = java.io.BufferedReader(java.io.InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    errorReader = java.io.BufferedReader(java.io.InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

    % initialize output char array
    cmdout = '';
    while true
        % If any lines are ready to read, append them to output
        % and display them if streamOutput is true
        if outputReader.ready() || errorReader.ready()
            if outputReader.ready()
                nextLine = char(outputReader.readLine());
            elseif errorReader.ready()
                nextLine = char(errorReader.readLine());
            end
            cmdout = [cmdout,nextLine,newline()];
            if streamOutput == true
                disp(nextLine);
            end
            continue
        else
            % if there are no lines ready in the reader, and the
            % process is no longer running, then we are done
            if ~process.isAlive()
                break
            end
            % Check for timeout.  If timeout is reached, destroy
            % the process and break
            if toc(timeoutTimer) > timeoutSeconds
                timeoutMessage = ['sys_with_timeout(''',command, ''',', num2str(timeoutSeconds), ')',...
                                  ' failed after timeout of ',num2str(toc(timeoutTimer)),' seconds'];
                if errorOnTimeout == true
                    error(timeoutMessage)
                else
                    warning(timeoutMessage)
                end
                process.destroyForcibly();
                break
            end
        end
    end
    if ~isempty(cmdout)
        cmdout(end) = []; % remove trailing newline of command output
    end
    status = process.exitValue(); % return
end
```

Replacing `ssh some-user@0.1.2.3` with `wsl` (requires [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) of course) for simplicity, here is an example of a function that times out:

```
>> [status,cmdout] = sys_with_timeout('wsl echo start! && sleep 2 && echo finished!',1)
start!
Warning: sys_with_timeout('wsl echo start! && sleep 2 && echo finished!',1) failed after timeout of 1.0002 seconds 
> In sys_with_timeout (line 41) 
status =
     1
cmdout =
    'start!'
```

and here is an example of a function that doesn't time out:

```
>> [status,cmdout] = sys_with_timeout('wsl echo start! && sleep 2 && echo finished!',3)
start!
finished!
status =
     0
cmdout =
    'start!
     finished!'
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the `system` command is very flexible, and I don't see a way to do what you want using it.
But we can use the Java functionality built into MATLAB for this, according to [this answer by André Caron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6710779/7328782).

This is how you'd wait for the process to finish with a timeout:

```matlab
runtime = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();
process = runtime.exec('sleep 20');
process.waitFor(10, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS);
if process.isAlive()
    disp("Done waiting for this...")
    process.destroyForcibly();
end
process.exitValue()
```

In the example, we run the `sleep 20` shell command, then `waitFor()` waits until the program finishes, but for a maximum of 10 seconds. We poll to see if the process is still running, and kill it if it is. `exitValue()` returns the status, if you need it.

Running `sleep 5` I see:

```
ans =
     0
```

Running `sleep 20` I see:

```
Done waiting for this...
ans =
   137
```

Comment: Thank you, I never knew about running Java commands from MATLAB.  This is very helpful.  I used different parts of your answer to build the function I want and posted it as a new answer.